# How do I have integers and decimal numbers aligned in the same column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, alignment

The custom number type `0,?` yields the following column:

[image: excel]

I want to get rid of the comma in the top entry. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think that is a valid custom number format.  When I try to format to this it converts it to `#,#0?` and I don't get the `2,` that you show.

Comment: @Rey Probably you do not see the same result, because of your decimal separator setting. Maybe, if you try with a dot instead of comma, you will see a similar result

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that for integer values, you want them aligned with the integer part of decimal values, but without the the decimal comma? If that is what you are looking for, I believe it is not possible. The alignment is based on the decimal separator.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes, that's what I'm looking for.